# Foreach after await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I got a problem with a foreach loop after an await call. The purchaseOrders is filled with 4 orders but the `foreach` stops every time before it reaches 4 iterations. The execution stops, and it doesn't run the `GetInvoices` call.

```
GetPurchaseOrders("50000");
GetInvoices("10000");

static async void GetPurchaseOrders(string supplier)
{
    var purchaseOrders = await VNA.PurchaseOrders.ForSupplierAsyncTask(supplier);

    foreach (var order in purchaseOrders)
    {
        CreateXMLDocument(order, order.orderNbr, "PurchaseOrder");
    }
}
```

Comment: what does tracing show you?

Comment: Is CreateXMLDocument a void? Or is perhaps an async method?

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock somewhere, did you try adding `ConfigureAwait`?

Comment: One of many reasons why you should avoid writing `async void` methods - there's no natural place for you to capture exceptions that are otherwise unhandled.

Comment: What are the contents of purchaseOrders according to the debugger if you break on the foreach line? Are there four orders? What is the return value of ForSupplierAsyncTask? Is it an IEnumerable that might stull be using delayed execution? Are you sure the ForSupplierAsyncTask uses ToList() or ToArray() or similar to force execution of the IEnumerable or IQueryable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using `async void`. Instead return `Task` or `Task<T>`. Consider the following:

```
static async Task GetPurchaseOrders(string supplier)
{
    try
    {
        var purchaseOrders = await VNA.PurchaseOrders.ForSupplierAsyncTask(supplier);

        foreach (var order in purchaseOrders)
        {
            CreateXMLDocument(order, order.orderNbr, "PurchaseOrder");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   // <-- Place a breakpoint here...
        // I would imagine you're getting an exception
    }
}
```

The `Task` (as a return type) is how the underlying async state-machine understands the correlation between states. Additionally, it allows for proper exception handling.

It is possible that you're using `IEnumerable<T>` over a database connection and since it is deferred execution plus suspended async execution, the connection might be closed before or during the attempt to iterate. The `try / catch` and proper usage of `Task` should help pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you only want to use async void when you have an asynchronous event handler. That's the only appropriate place to have an async void.